How to access an external package in a file
I came across the youtube video for accessing external package by specifying in .cabal in a project. But how to access the package in a single file.
Suppose I want to write a simple file and do some stuff in it. Can I import an external package such as System.Random ? Can I compile it using ghc without error?
Note: I am not using the project in this case. So I am not using cabal. Only a single file and compiling using ghc or loading in ghci

You add random to the dependencies in the cabal file, if you build it, the Haskell stack (if you use that) will download and install the package.

If you don't use cabal (or stack, or anything that builds on top of cabal), there is not much use to define a .cabal file.

I have just gave an example of how to access external package in a project. But my question is only to a single file without cabal

well you can do that, essentially what cabal will do for you is download the packages, and fire the haskell compiler with references to the installed packages. But manually doing that makes it a lot more painful than it should be. The easiest is probably Haskell stack, which will install the packages in a local environment.

To some extent it is a bit like Python without tools like pip, or another package manager. Sure you can download the package yourself, and then add it to the Python path, but it is really painful to do that.

You can see my answer in the original question which uses environment file in the local directory. That seems to be simpler

The System.Random module [Hackage] is defined in the random package [Hackage].
You can add random to the dependencies in the cabal file:
-- …
library
  -- …
  build-depends:
      base >= 4.7 && < 5
    , random >=1.0 && <2.0
  -- …
If you build it with cabal build or Haskell stack, so stack build, it will download the package and expose it to the modules of your project, so you can import it.

I am not using the project in this case. So I am not using cabal. Only a single file and compiling using ghc or loading in ghci

If you don't use cabal (or tools like Haskell stack that essentially built on top of cabal), there is not much need to work with a .cabal file.
In that case you can call the compiler with a list of packages to expose:
ghc -package random MyFile.hs
Then it looks in the package database, you can define a different one where you download and build the packages that you want to expose to your project.

Can you also add the method using stack. Is there an easier way to do it using stack for multiple packages ?

@Abhisek: just stack build, it will look for the .cabal file in the directory where you run it. So if you have two directories with a .cabal file, the two will act independently of each other.
